# My hybrid (Ionic) app breaks when used with VPN connection

Tags: http, ionic-framework, vpn

I have come across an issue where my Ionic application 'hangs' on tasks that are performing HTTP requests.

Are there any conventions for handling use cases where VPN is enabled ?

Should there be any difference in a HTTP request with a device that has VPN enabled to a device that doesn't ?

What measures should I be taking to ensuring I am developing an application that handles use cases like this ?

EDIT

In the HTTP headers the arguments and caller field both have this type error message.

> TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in strict mode.